# Calculating website for kids, Sessions resetting

Tags: php, html, session, calculator

For school I have to make a calculating website for kids. Everything works so far except for the most important part - the calculating. So far I came up with this. (I know it's not really a clean code. I am very new to this and I just can't figure it out.)

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['vraagnr']))
{
    $vraagnr=$_SESSION['vraagnr'];
}
else
{
if(empty($vraagnr))
{
$vraagnr = 0;
}
else
{
    $goed=0;
    $_SESSION['goed'] = $goed;
if($vraagnr<10)
{
    $goed=0;
    $getal1=rand(0,10);
    $getal2=rand(0,10);
    $vraagnr++;
    echo $vraagnr;
    $antwoord=$_POST['antwoord'];
    $uitkomst=$getal1+$getal2;
    $vraag = $getal1 . "+" . $getal2;
    $_SESSION['vraagnr'] = $vraagnr;
    if($antwoord==$getal1+$getal2)
    {
        $goed++;
    }
    echo $goed;


}
else
{

    echo "Je bent klaar met de oefening.";
    echo "je hebt $goed aantal vragen goed beantwoord";
}
    $_SESSION['vraagnr']=$vraagnr;

    }


?>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "".$vraag."" ?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="antwoord"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

</html>
```

The idea is that you get 10 questions(randomly) after 10 questions you should see how many answers were correct. `$vraagnr` needs to count how many questions you had and `$goed` how many of them were correct.

I hope you can give me some tips.

Comment: Your main issue is that you're reading from `$_SESSION['goed']`, but never assigning back to it - you need to add the value of `$goed` back into the session if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I'm at school and I cannot really test out the code I wrote but you should follow this structure.

```
while($couter < 10) {
$numberone = rand(5, 15); 
   $numbertwo = rand(5, 15); 
$answer = $numberone + $numbertwo;

echo "De vraag is: Hoeveel is <?php echo $numberone . " + " . $numbertwo;?>";

if ($answer == $input) als het antwoord juist is..
else als het antwoord niet juist is..

$counter++;
}
```

Comment: I suppose i should put the form above if($answer == $input) because it would not recognize $input otherwise?